# Laravel Polymorphic Relations commentable_type validation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using a REST API to receive the data.
The data model is polymorphic related, similar to the one on the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text

videos
    id - integer
    title - string
    url - string

comments
    id - integer
    body - text
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string
```

Let's say, for example, the API is receiving this new comment:

```
{
    "body": "This a test comment",
    "commentable_type": "posts",
    "commentable_id": "1"
}
```

How can I validate if the received commentable_type exists and is valid?

Answer (score 10):

If I correctly understand your question, you are trying to validate that the object of the polymorphic relation exists, for the given `commentable_type` and `commentable_id`.

If that is the case, there is no existing validation rule to do so, but you can create one.
Based on [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules), here is what you could do:

First, add the new rule in the `boot` method of a service provider (e.g. `AppServiceProvider`):

```
Validator::extend('poly_exists', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    if (!$objectType = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[0], false)) {
        return false;
    }

    return !empty(resolve($objectType)->find($value));
});
```

And this is how you would use it:

```
'commentable_id' => 'required|poly_exists:commentable_type
```

What the rule does is it tries and fetches the commentable type from the input values (based on the parameter passed on to the rule, i.e. `commentable_type` in our case), and then resolves the object and tries to find a record for the given ID (`$value`).

Please note that for this to work however, the value of `commentable_type` must be the fully qualified class name (e.g. `App\Models\Post`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had the exact same question, and tried to use your snippet but couldn't get it working, so not sure what I did wrong. If I drop the validation rule then of course it works fine, but the moment I add it in back into the FormRequest, I get the error "The commentable id field is required."

Comment: @seekay it seems it doesn't find the `commentable_id` field in your input then. Can you show me an example request you're trying to make?

Comment: here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/chandank/f269f0860d4fd01459ce4997600ec10c) - I think the reason is that I'm using route model binding. I guess it would work if I include a hidden field with the `commentable_id` in the form, but that seems hacky. Thoughts/suggestions? I can open a separate question if easier.

Comment: @seekay I see, your case is quite different from the author's. But since your `Task` object is already resolved through model binding, and that this `Task` object is actually the model of the polymorphic relation, isn't it validated already?

Comment: it seemed to me that the case was similar i.e. I need to be able to validate the commentable_id. That being said, I guess you are correct in that the Task object is automatically validated because of the route model binding (otherwise Laravel would throw an error). Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Better approach that includes morphs map:

```
    Validator::extend('poly_exists', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        if (! $type = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[0], false)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (Relation::getMorphedModel($type)) {
            $type = Relation::getMorphedModel($type);
        }

        if (! class_exists($type)) {
            return false;
        }

        return ! empty(resolve($type)->find($value));
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically define a `model_exists` rule in your Request class. Something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $polymorphExistsRule = '';
    if ($this->has('commentable_type')) {
        $polymorphExistsRule .= '|exists:' . $this->commentable_type . ',id';
    }

    return [
        'commentable_type' => 'required_with:commentable_id',
        'commentable_id'   => 'required_with:commentable_type' . $polymorphExistsRule,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

I might've misunderstood the first time. If you want to check that the model saved in `commentable_type` exists you could do something like this:

```
$type = $comment->commentable_type;
if(class_exists($type)) echo "it exists";
```

Depending on your needs you could do additional checking for it's [inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) (for example that it extends class `Model`). Or anything else that fits your needs really.

**Edit2**

This is what I would do if I were you. I would add property `protected $allRelations` to your `Comment` model and manually put all the relationships in. Then make some helper models to check if it's in the array.

Simple example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    // ..

    protected $allRelations= [
        'posts' => '\App\Post',
        'videos' => '\App\Video',
    ];

    public static function validateRelationNs($ns) {
        return in_array($ns, $this->allRelations);
    }

    public static function validateRelationName($name) {
        return array_key_exists($name, $this->allRelations);
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Old answer:**

Laravel expects full namespace name of the model for polymorphic type columns (in your case `commentable_type` should be `\Full\Ns\Post`, not `posts`).

The easiest way to ensure correctness is to always save it [through the relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method). For example:

```
$post = Post::first();
$comment = new Comment($attributes);
$post->comments()->save($comment).
```

This will automatically set both `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` correctly (assuming your relationsare correctly defined).

**Additional checking**

Other then that you could check through model [events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events). You could validate it before saving to the database.

Comment: I think that the data should be validated before trying to insert on database. Somehow get all models related to the comments model on the validation phase.

Comment: Oh, so you want to check that the model actually exists after receiving the json of already saved comment? I misunderstood the first time.

Comment: Not exactly, I want to check if the model exists and is polymorphic related to, in this case, Comments model.

Comment: I mean the whole point of polymorphic relationship is that it can belong to any class. So I dont understand "and is polymorphic related to" part. You can check if the model exists with my updated answer.

Comment: In order to exist a commentable relation you have to declare something like this: return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable'); in each of the models that can have comments. What I'm looking for is a way of determining if the commentable_type parameter is a valid model and is related to comments model.

Comment: You don't _need_ to define the `$this->morphMany()` part for the relationship to exist. You could technically have a relationship that only gets called from the inverse and it's still a valid relationship (for example if all you need is queries like `Comment::with('posts')->get()` and you save the post through Comment, you don't need a relationship on posts). You need to define for yourself what it means that relationship exists and validate based on that.

Comment: I might also need Comment::with('videos')->get(); Want to have all persisted on the same database table: Comments.

Comment: There is no easy solution for what you want. I suggest you do add an array property to your Comment model that holds the names of all relationships and manually add all the relationships to that array. Then you check if the `commentable_type` is in the relationships array.

Comment: Thks a lot for the tips, devk!

Answer (score 0):

My final version work for validate type and id:

```
Validator::extend('poly_exists', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    if (!$objectType = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[0], false)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!class_exists($objectType)) {
        return false;
    }

    return !empty(resolve($objectType)->find($value));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something that:

```
/**
 * Store a new comment.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'body' => 'required',
        'commentable_id' => 'required|exists:' . $request->commentable_type . ',id',
    ]);
 
    // The comment is valid...
}
```